# Save bulk of rows at one time using Angular js ,Spring,hibernate

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, bulkinsert

Code snippet which i have posted is working fine and values are saving into DB. But what actually i need is to save the list of rows at a time for one shot.How can i achieve this using Angularjs for updating each and every row.Hope anyone could help me with this issue.

**reference link** for UI view

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1028442/Bulk-Upload-in-AngularJS

**analysis.html**

```
<select ng-model="analysis.state" ng-options="state.stateName as state.stateName for state in stateList" x-ng-change="updateDistrict(analysis.state)">
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="analysis.itemName"  ng-options="product.itemName as product.itemName for product in itemList">
<option value="">Select Item</option>
</select>

<input name="minimumPrice" ng-model="analysis.minimumPrice" placeholder="Minimum Price" required />
<input name="maximumPrice" ng-model="analysis.maximumPrice" placeholder="Maximum Price" required />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
```

**saveController.js**

```
scope.saveAnalysis = function(analysis) {
    Repository.saveAnalysis(analysis)
        .then(function(response) {
                var status = response.statusMessage;
                    if (status = "success") {
                        alert("Record added successfully....!!");
                        state.go('analyserhome');
                        } else {
                        alert("Details Saving Fail...!!")
                        state.go("home");
                }
            });
        };
```

**Repository.js**
Newly added code

```
this.saveAnalysis = function(analysis){

var defer = $q.defer(); 
//defer is units of work,promise is data from those defer
rootScope.marketPrice = [{
    "itemName" : "xyz",
    "minimumPrice" : "111",
    "maximumPrice" : "222",
    "marketName":"xyz",
    "unitofPrice":"xyz",
    "category":"xyz",
    "marketPlace":"xyz",
    "state":"xyz",
    "district":"xyz"
},{
    "itemName" : "xyz",
    "minimumPrice" : "555",
    "maximumPrice" : "666",
    "marketName":"xyz",
    "unitofPrice":"xyz",
    "category":"xyz",
    "marketPlace":"xyz",
    "state":"xyz",
    "district":"xyz"
}];
var analysisPromise = http.post('/project/saveAnalysis/',rootScope.marketPrice);

analysisPromise.then(function(response){ 
    analysis =response.data;
    defer.resolve(analysis);
});
return defer.promise;
```

};

**Price.java**

```
public class MarketPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "itemId")
private Long itemId;

@Column(name = "itemName")
private String itemName;

@Column(name = "minimumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
private Float minimumPrice;

@Column(name = "maximumPrice",columnDefinition = "Float(10,2)")
private Float maximumPrice;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;

//getters and setters
```

}

**SaveAnalysis.java**
//Changes i have made in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/saveAnalysis"} , method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public MarketPrice bulkSaveMarketAnalysis(@RequestBody 
        List<MarketPrice> marketPrices, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request){

    MarketPrice marketPrice1 = new MarketPrice();
    System.out.println("List data:"+marketPrices.get(0)+""+marketPrices);
    String marketDataResponse = analyserService.saveListOfMarketPrice(marketPrices);
    System.out.println(marketDataResponse);
    marketPrice1.setStatusMessage("success");
    return marketPrice1;
}

}
```

**SaveAnalysisDAO.java**

```
public String saveListOfMarketPrice(List<MarketPrice> marketPrices) {
    System.out.println("In Analyser DAO fro bulk saving");
    final Session session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    for (MarketPrice price : marketPrices) {
        System.out.println("In save method using for each loop");
        session.save(price);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return "success";
    }
    return null;
}
```

When user enters his all data ,entire list should save into DB .But here state will be selected only once which will be updated to each row.

After changing list of 2 records is being passed to controller. and only one record is saving into DB. i.e for each loop is being executed only once.

**Main issue am facing now is values should come from html page**

Thank you,in advance.

Comment: So you are creating a bulk update query (and not executing it) and saving the passed MarketPRice. Is not invoking the bulk intenrional and should the save be invoked after the bulk update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your backend for a bulk update solution.

---

**Front-end**

On your front-end application, create a valid json containing a list of MarketPrices.

**E.g. of valid object ->**

```
var analysis = [
    {
        "state": "A",
        "itemName": "Test#1",
        "minimumPrice": 11.2,
        "maximumPrice": 10.2
    },
    {
        "state": "A",
        "itemName": "Test#2",
        "minimumPrice": 11.2,
        "maximumPrice": 10.2
    },
    {
        "state": "A",
        "itemName": "Test#3",
        "minimumPrice": 11.2,
        "maximumPrice": 10.2
    }
];
```

Send a Json containing an array of MarketPrices on your post request body (data).

**Repository snippet**

```
saveAnalysis = function(analysis)   {
    $http({
        url: 'request-url',
        method: 'POST',
        data: analysis
        })
    .then(function(response)    {
    //HANDLE success
    }, function(errorResponse)  {
    //HANDLE error
    });
};
```

---

**Back-end**

Create a new method on your controller that receives a List of MarketPrice.

**SaveAnalysis**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/bulkSsaveAnalysis"} , method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response bulkSaveMarketAnalysis(@RequestBody List<MarketPrice> marketPrices, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
```

**Service layer:**

Isolate your validation method (if exists) so you could reuse it for a single object or a list. And then, create a new method which receives a list and create a new row on database one by one.

```
for(MarketPrice price : martketPrices)  {
    //call your validation or helpers methods
    //Here you have to choose what to do on fail scenario
    saveAnalysisDAO.saveMarketPrice(price);
}
```

There is a problem in this design: What happens when any one the transactions fail? Should you rollback everyone? Should you store the errors and send a new list containing which one failed and who succeeded to the front-end?

You have to choose what is the best scenario for error handling to your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How exactly can i change front end code to exactly receive list object.As per your answer i have changed server side code.

Comment: Hello @Hema, I've edited the answer adding an example how to change the code on the front-end side. Hope it clear your doubts.